# Which use of the て形 is used in this picture?

Tags: grammar

The only thing I remember is that the て form may mean "and" but and in this context have no sense.

[image]

Comment: Your confusion came from assuming the subject of こまって was 学校のべんきょう, (rather than how to interpret the て) no? It's implied 私は, as in **私は** 、学校のべんきょうがむつかしくて、こまっています。 "The study at school is difficult, **and/so** I'm in trouble."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > 学校の　べんきょうが　むずかしく**て、**  （......）います。
>
> The only thing I remember is that the て form may mean "and" but and in this context have no sense.

The use of て is not limited to mean 'and'.
In this case it's used to indicate the ***reason*** of the conclusion of the predicate.

> **2** 原因・理由を表す。…ので。…ために。「頭が痛くて寝ていた」（[デジタル大辞泉 | て | **１-2**](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/148945/meaning/m1u/%E3%81%A6/)）

Comment: So it works as a から? how do I know when using what?

Comment: Yes, から works as ので: むずかしいから／むずかしいので. I see that the conjugation of むずかしい is different. They just come to us without any effort though... How? Keep your dictionary handy. :)

Answer (score 0):

In this context, it means something along the lines of "so difficult".  So the first part of the sentence reads,

> My studies for school are so difficult, I'm frustrated.

I'll leave for you to figure out which verb to use.

Comment: I know the answer, is こまって but I still don't understand why is the て形 used

Comment: it creates the meaning of "so ..."

Comment: So the translation would be?

Comment: I think you tried to mean 'so' in "[reason], so [conclusion]", but this て is more like the 'because' in  "because [reason], [conclusion]." :)

Comment: @LuisFernandoBadelMéndez i thought i'd provided that in my answer above already.

Comment: @karlalou  i meant "so" as in "so difficult that i got frustrated".

Comment: @A.Ellett I see. I can agree that this て is like English 'that', but not 'so'; it's a conjunction but not an adverb.